# Can I directly load data Shared by another user on drive in my Colab notebook?

Tags: deep-learning, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train a CNN on a 40GB dataset. The data is publically available on google drive at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mSLgwVTiaUMAb4AVOWwlCD5JcWdrwpvu I have seen methods using Github and Mount_Drive. But is there a way to directly load data in my design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
!gdown --id 1mSLgwVTiaUMAb4AVOWwlCD5JcWdrwpvu
```

Use GPU instance, so that you will have enough space.